# Using realative paths in Angular: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, path

Helloo,
I am trying to import a class from a different component in Angular. But I keep getting error the Error:

```
Cannot find module './app/_services/modal.service' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

My import statement looks like this

```js
import {ModalService} from './app/_services/modal.service';
```

My directory tree looks like this, I am trying to go from the chatcomponent to _services:

- src

  - /app

    - /_services
    - /chat-app

      - /chat/chatcomponent.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the import path from src folder `src/app/_services/modal.service` or you should move back two folders so to reach _services folder `../../_services/modal.service`

Comment: thanks mate. It worked with the ../../_services, using the complete path from src folder did not work for some reason. I had that before..